# Define lower chest ( dumbells of 5 kg -after 10kg and goes on ) - Home

Tags: workout-routines, dumbbells, chest, upper-body-workout

I have seen many answers on how "to define the lower chest".

I see something interesting as an answer "**As your feet go higher, you're targeting more of the lower-chest.**"   Is that true first?

Second, as I read the answers you can't create a "**define lower chest from only push ups**" , so I came here to ask about using only dumbels.I am in home, can someone create a define lower chest using only dumbels he has on his home?

I have checked some exercises,but there are a lot of informations about it.It creates me a confusion.I came here cause someone is expert and will give me a better information on what I can do.

I mean:

a)How many sets-reps I must do in each exercise
example-I must do 3 sets of 10 reps with 5 kg

b)how much I must relax between the sets - I have read that it is 40second until 60second max.

c)Usually , I don't know if that applies to lower chest. I must give 48h rest.

If it is easy ,I would like as an answer some photos. It will help me and will help other guys too.

Answer (score 1):

Lowerchest is part of pectoral major. The other chest muscle is pectoral minor, which sits underneath pec major to the outside of chest. You can't 100% isolate a part of the pec major, but most people believe that you can preferentially target the upper or lower fibers of the pec major by doing either incline bench (for upper chest) or decline bench (for lower chest). If you don't have an adjustable bench you'll have to be creative. If you can find some way to do chest dips that might be the best bodyweight solution.

Putting your feet on top of something (like a chair or whatever) while doing push-ups would target upper chest, so to target lower chest you could put your hands on top of something, but that's also going to shift more weight to your feet, which reduces the overall resistance level you experience.

Since you have dumbbells, if you can find some way to do a decline dumbbell bench press that'd be ideal.[image: Decline Dumbbell Benchpress]

[image: Chest Muscle Anatomy]

A) Exactly how many sets and reps to do is hotly debated. There are countless articles in the bodybuilding community about this. For a beginner I would recommend selecting a weight such that you can do no more than 12 reps. For example, if you're using the same weight for each set you might do 12 reps on first set (and could have done more) do 12 reps again on second set with greater difficulty, and then only be able to do 10 reps on last set. I would argue that pushing yourself hard - but safely - is far more important than the specific numbers.

B) Again, don't overthink it. Doing one set of 4 reps with maximal exertion will probably give you at least 70% of the strength gains and hypertrophy of doing the perfect, holy-grail set with the number of reps, sets, and the time between sets perfected. For a whole body exercise like deadlifts or squats I'd definitely take more time, maybe even 5min depending how you're feeling, but for training chest 60 seconds should be fine and allow you to maintain pump.

C) Recovery time for chest is about the same as any other skeletal muscle. I would recommend training chest hard 2-3 times per week spaced out evenly.

Comment: I tried decline bench for the first and last time a few weeks ago. Nausea city. Something about having my head lower than the rest of me. I guess it happens when you get older.

Comment: If you get nausea from the declining position, maybe using cable weights or rubber bands would be an option? So instead of changing the position, change the direction of the force.